# Passing a function directly vs anonymous function, to a then promise callback

Tags: javascript, callback, promise, es6-promise

I am trying to understand the difference between the 3 options:

```
.then(myCallback)

.then(myCallback())

.then(() => { myCallback() })
```

The `myCallback` function returns nothing and is used only for its side effects, so I don't need it to pass anything back to the promise chain. What I don't understand is why in my code only the second option triggers the function, when it seems like all the 3 should.

UPDATE: Here is the code with the bare essentials

```
serverCall(url, data) // fetch function
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then(myCallback) // not running, only when () added
  .catch((error) => { console.log(error) })

const myCallback = () => { 
  anotherServerCall(...).then(...)
}
```

UPDATE 2

After some digging I see that having `.then((response) => response.json())` as the first `then response` is what is preventing `.then(myCallback)` to execute. Still no idea why...

Comment: Are you resolving the promise? The second one _calls_ the function and passes the result to `then`, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: As pointed out by @tkausl, it seems like the promise is not being resolved for these callbacks to be executed.

Comment: The `then` is for `fetch` so I assume the callback is being resolved

Comment: But then the functions should've been called. Options 1 and 3 look fine, if they are not called your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: You should add `myCallback` to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All three should trigger the function, but the order differs between the approaches.  If you're sometimes seeing evidence that the `serverCall` or `myCallback` aren't being invoked, then that has something to do with the particulars of those functions, not the ways you are calling them.

To demonstrate, consider two proxies for `serverCall` and `myCallback` that we know will always work.  Let's apply each idea in your question to those:

1. This is the "normal" way to use `then`. Pass it a function that is invoked *after* the promise to which it is attached...

```js
function serverCall() {
    console.log('began server call');
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('completed server call');
            resolve();
        }, 2);
    });
}

function myCallback() {
    console.log('callback called');
}

serverCall().then(myCallback).then(() => console.log('done'));

// produces: 
// began server call
// completed server call
// callback called
// done
```

2. Your first and third ideas are almost the same.  Pass then a function which is invoked after the promise.  In your third idea, the function isn't the callback, it's a function that calls the callback.  One more stack frame, but the exact same effect...

```js
function serverCall() {
    console.log('began server call');
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('completed server call');
            resolve();
        }, 2);
    });
}
    
function myCallback() {
    console.log('callback called');
}


serverCall().then(() => { myCallback() }).then(() => console.log('done'))

// produces:
// began server call
// completed server call
// callback called
// done
```

3. Your second idea, as a commenter points out, invokes the function and passes it's result to `then`.  The chaining of the `then` runs synchronously after starting the promise, so the results appear reordered: `myCallback` runs before the promise completes...

```js
function serverCall() {
    console.log('began server call');
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('completed server call');
            resolve();
        }, 2);
    });
}
    
function myCallback() {
    console.log('callback called');
}


serverCall().then(myCallback()).then(() => console.log('done'))

// produces:
// began server call
// callback called         <------ CHANGED!!!
// completed server call
// done
```

Comment: Got it, thanx! Still, for some reason this .then((response) => response.json()).then(myCallback) does not trigger myCallback. Only when I remove the first then it works.

Comment: @ilyo, one cause of that would be if the json method throws an error, the rest of the promises would be skipped.  If you put `.catch(err => console.log(err))` at the end, you might discover that's where execution flowed

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found to duplicate your problem is if the callback returns a function. Options 1 and 3 don't do anything because the returned function isn't being called. Option 2 *is* called and is successful.

```js
function fetch() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve();
  });
}

function myCallBack() {
  return function () {
    console.log('Success');
  };
}

fetch().then(myCallBack); // nothing
fetch().then(myCallBack()); // Success
fetch().then(() => myCallBack()); // nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use cases are different because

The first one `then` call, you are passing a `callback` to be invoked when then it’s executed, passing a naming function will appear in the stack trace if some error occurred

The second one, execute the `callback` passed before being passed to the `then` function and the result of that execution callback will be passing to the `then` function, so imagine this.

```
function myCallback(){
        return function   theRealCallbackPassed(thenResponse){
          // do something with then response
        }
    }
```

The last one, will define an anonymous arrow function , so what is the diff between

```
then( () => {} )
```

And

```
then( function(){} )
```

The different is that using arrow function `() => {}` you have a short syntax and you are binded the function contexto to the current context where the arrow function it’s declared.

While the `function() {}` syntax is not shorter and it is not auto bindable.

Hope it can help you.